# bind helper like get & mut? How to bind input to dynamically specified property?

Tags: ember.js

I can use the `input` helper to toggle a boolean property of an `item` like so:

```
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.isSelected}}
```

If I want a template that displays a property of an item, but the property name is passed in dynamically, I can use the `get` helper.

```
{{get item propertyName}}
```

Can I combine the two approaches to bind the checkboxes `checked` attribute to a dynamically specified property?

```
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=(?bind? item propertyName)}}
```

At the moment I am using the workaround below, but it seems inelegant to me (wrongly so?).

```
  {{input type="checkbox"
  checked=(get item propertyName)
  action=(toggle propertyName item) on="change"}}
```

Comment: you can combine mut and get helper like the below  {{input type="checkbox" checked=(mut (get item propertyName))}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can combine `get` and `mut` helper. `{{get}}` helper can also respect mutable values itself . sample [Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4e9504019a8ffa7bfb5a31309b54d40b?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=(mut (get item propertyName))}}
```

Get Helper reference: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get